# error using apply.yearly inside xts package. How this works?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have been using ts objects for a while but not too much xts, so i was trying to calculate mean, sum, last, first... (FUN) for every year in economic time series. When i try it i have weird result.

This is a quick example:
Considering x and y like monthly series, for two consecutive years:

```
x <- 1:12
y <- 1:12
serie <- c(x,y)
```

Then i create a ts object

```
serie <- ts(serie,1990,,12)
```

now i convert it to xts object

```
library(xts)

serie.xts <- as.xts(serie)

plot(serie.xts)
```

as far i see, the series is properly  created

```
serie.xts
```

The series looks ok

```
ene 1990    1
feb 1990    2
mar 1990    3
abr 1990    4
may 1990    5
jun 1990    6
jul 1990    7
ago 1990    8
sep 1990    9
oct 1990   10
nov 1990   11
dic 1990   12
ene 1991    1
feb 1991    2
mar 1991    3
abr 1991    4
may 1991    5
jun 1991    6
jul 1991    7
ago 1991    8
sep 1991    9
oct 1991   10
nov 1991   11
dic 1991   12
```

Then comes my problem

for example, i try to get the last value for every year, as far i know this is what this function do:

```
apply.yearly(serie.xts,FUN = "last")
```

but i get this:

```
ene 1990    1
ene 1991    1
dic 1991   12
```

I was expecting this:
dic 1990   12
dic 1991   12

What am i doing wrong?
Is this the way this function works?
What this function do actually?

i don't understand what is this result.
Please help. And thanks for reading my question.

R 3.3.3
xts  0.9-7
zoo 1.8-0

Comment: i try this, but also give me the same result: `period.apply(INDEX = endpoints(x = serie.xts,
                               on = "years"),
             x = serie.xts,
             FUN = "last")
`

Comment: I tried your code, and it works fine for me. I would suggest to convert the class of your index from `yearmon` to `Date` like this `index(serie.xts) <- as.Date(index(serie.xts))`

Comment: That is weird. I try in another pc and i have the same wrong result. Are you using the same version?

Comment: On macOS Sierra, R 3.3.3 xts 0.9-7, zoo 1.7-14

Comment: The only difference is the zoo version. Maybe this update broke something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in xts 0-9.7 that has been fixed in the development version. Run one of these commands to install from GitHub:

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")
# or
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")
```

Then the `apply.yearly` call will work as you expect:

```
serie <- ts(c(1:12,1:12),1990,,12)
library(xts)
serie.xts <- as.xts(serie)
apply.yearly(serie.xts, last)
#          [,1]
# Dec 1990   12
# Dec 1991   12
```